# Java Substring: Why is this going out of bounds sometimes?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

```
String inputOrig = event.getMessage();
inputHist += inputOrig;
inputHist = inputHist.substring(Math.max(0, inputHist.length()-256));
```

The bottom line will occasionally cause and IndexOutOfBounds exception with a negative index, but I thought that shouldn't be possible because I'm taking the greater of an expression and a zero. it should be defaulting to zero shouldn't it?

edit: this is the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
```

there's another just like it with an index of -20, and the next line just points to the method this code is in.

I'm trying to use inputHist as a history of event.getMessage() that caps at 256 characters and I thought this worked. This or at the least something similar worked before in my code but I'm not sure if I accidentally changed something or other, and if I did I can't tell what it is.

Comment: Can you show us the exception message?

Comment: From what you describe, the code you want is probably `inputHist.substring(0, Math.min(inputHist.length(), 256))`. But it's unclear why you get that negative index error.

Comment: What input string causes the error? Check the value in your debugger before the substring() function is run.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele that wouldn't work correctly because I'm appending new messages to the end of the history, so I need to trim excess characters from the beginning of the string.

Comment: The only idea I have is that this might have to do with concurrency and race conditions.

Comment: Can you print the length of the `inputHist` after doing `inputHist += inputOrig;`

Comment: With `Math.max(0, xxx)`, you can never get a `-2`, so the error cannot be from *that* line of code.

Answer (score 0):

So I was correct in saying that that line was supposed to be working. The issue was with the other substring I was using in the method that I managed to completely miss. Later on in the method I am removing inputOrig from the history if it meets certain criteria, in order to prevent a feedback loop.

```
inputHist = inputHist.substring(0,inputHist.length()-inputOrig.length());
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix it yet but that would be an entirely different question. I'll keep looking and ask it later if I can't solve it. Thank you all for your help and bearing with my mistake.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question then because it is describing problem which didn't really exist (at least wasn't related to code you showed). You will lose reputation from this question though but that still looks like proper action here IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When your inputOrigin has the lenght of 0 can cause index out of bound becaue indexes are start from 0 then the last character of the string is its length -1 
I think you should add -1 to your upper limit and check the different conditions again

Comment: event.getMessage() can't return zero because then the method this code is in doesn't get triggered.